# Logon to website using domain credentials onto remote domain with the same name as a local domain does not work

Tags: dns, browser

We have an internal domain where users logon to. We also have a cloud based solution with multiple websites that are also in a domain there.

However the domain names (netbios) are exactly the same.

When using RDP to logon to the computers in the cloud using the credentials for that domain causes no problems at all, but when we try to logon to a website there which uses the domain in the cloud, the browser defaults to the local domain and then the authentication fails.

Is there a way to make the browser look to the online domain to authenticate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the names are exactly the same? Try to logon with something like YOURUSERNAME@YOURDOMAIN.SOMETHING where something is the full domain name on the cloud based solution (for example JDoe@Doesdomain.local)